# Как подключить шрифты Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, шрифты

Сейчас я создаю ТГ бота на *aiogram*, Python для себя (управление каналом). Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать нечто подобное @TextChangerBot . Мне необходимо выделять текст, отправленный пользователям перенаправлять в канал уже со шрифтом. У меня была идея циклом for проходится по всем буквам, и заменять их своими же копиями из шрифта, но получилось бы слишком громоздко, и (как я думаю) некорректно. Подскажите пожалуйста методы, которые могут мне помочь

Comment: шрифт - это внешний вид букв. Т.е. форматирование. Заменять буквы их копиями из другого шрифта  - довольно бессмысленная фраза. Если форматирование останется тем же, то ничего и не изменится. Нужно менять форматирование, а не буквы.

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но в том боте, которого я указал не форматирование текста (в моём представлении форматирование - жирный, курсив, подчёркнутый, моноширинный, зачёркнутый), а буквально шрифты. Посмотрите:
'     или '    

Comment: Форматирование это не только жирный, курсив и т.д., но и вид шрифта. Когда вы в ворде меняете таймс нью роман на какой-нибудь ариал, то буквы не заменяются. Меняется файл, из которого берется их внешний вид. А в ваших примерах не шрифт в классическом понимании. Там для каждой буквы отдельный код. Потому что эти тексты не идентичны. Попробуйте поискать на странице here, результат будет 1 (мой комментарий), хотя должно было бы быть 3 - 1 раз у меня и 2 раза у вас.

Comment: Я поискал и сделал скриншот результата: https://i.imgur.com/mj0EgBC 
Он нашёл слово here 3 раза, как будто это тоже слово поверх которого наложен шрифт

Comment: О. Странно. Хром действительно находит, а ФФ нет.

Comment: Так я могу как-то задавать шрифты для текста с помощью Питона?

Comment: да наверняка можно, только я не знаю как

Comment: Это не шрифты. Это креативное использование символов юникода. В частности в вашем примере буквы взяты из https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/

Comment: В частности бува `` из вашего примера https://unicode-table.com/en/1D691/
Ну, т.е. ваша первая идея верна, нужно в цикле пройтись по строке и заменить нормальные буквы вот этими буквами из математического блока юникода.

Comment: @Эникейщик видимо хром умеет искать по нормализованным формам, а firefox нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, так и сделал. Теперь всё работает!

Comment: @PavloG добавьте получившийся код ответом? кому-то может быть полезным...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как меня просили, добавляю свой ответ:

Я действительно циклом прошёлся по всему слову, и заменил все буквы на их соответствующие версии в шрифте. Прикрепляю код:

```
def beautiful_name(string):
    for i in string:
        try:
            is_new_title = istitle(i)
            new_letter = font[i.lower()][is_new_title]
            string = string.replace(i, new_letter)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return string
```

А также оставляю [файл JSON](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mg4tAvuNYnwFtP3deBLJ0qxVVwJfpF7U/view?usp=sharing) в котором хранится самодельный "шрифт". Вам нужно лишь выгрузить этот файл в словарь font и дело в шляпе!

И чуть не забыл: там используется моя функция istitle(), поэтому оставлю и её код:

```
def istitle(letter):
    if letter == letter.title():
        return "big"
    else:
        return "small"
```